# How do I configure an auto-repairing & auto-scaling Google Cloud Kubernetes cluster with Terraform with stackdriver disabled

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I was reading [this](https://www.doxsey.net/blog/kubernetes--the-surprisingly-affordable-platform-for-personal-projects) blog on setting up an affordable Kubernetes cluster for personal projects, and setup my cluster.

Trouble is, I tend to forget a lot of manual configuration over time, so I decided to store it in declarative code using Terraform.

I've managed to build the following configuration, and apply it:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("secret-account.json")}"
  project     = "worklark-218609"
  zone      = "us-central1-a"
}

# configuration
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name               = "worklark-cluster"
  initial_node_count = 3

  node_config {
    machine_type = "f1-micro"
    disk_size_gb = 10 # Set the initial disk size
    preemptible = true
  }

  addons_config {
    kubernetes_dashboard {
      disabled = false # Configure the Kubernetes dashboard
    }

    http_load_balancing {
      disabled = false # Configure the Kubernetes dashboard
    }

  }
}
```

The problem is, the two clusters are slightly differently configured, here's what I need to add to the configuration:

- Stackdriver Logging: is currently Enabled, *must be **Disabled***.
- Stackdriver Monitoring: is currently Enabled, *must be **Disabled***.
- Automatic node upgrades: is currently Disabled, *must be **Enabled***.
- Automatic node repair: is currently Disabled, *must be **Enabled***.

I can't find the configuration options on the documentation for the [`google_container_cluster`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#) resource. What do I do to set these options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the options:

- Stackdriver Logging: called `logging_service` under [`google_container_cluster`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#)
- Stackdriver Monitoring: called `monitoring_service` under [`google_container_cluster`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#)
- Automatic node upgrades: called `management.auto_upgrade` under [`container_node_pool`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_node_pool.html)
- Automatic node repair: called `management.auto_repair` under [`container_node_pool`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_node_pool.html)`

The `container_node_pool` options aren't applicable to the default pool created with the cluster, unfortunately, so a workaround I found was to delete the default pool, and then add a fully configured node pool to the cluster.

Here's the final config:

```
/* This configuration sets up a Kubernetes Cluster following
   https://www.doxsey.net/blog/kubernetes--the-surprisingly-affordable-platform-for-personal-projects

   Confession: there's a minor difference between the article and my config, the
   former created a Cluster and configured the default node pool, however the options
   for doing this via the API are limited, so my configuration creates an empty
   default node pool for the cluster, and the creates and adds a fully configured
   one on top
    */

provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("secret-account.json")}"
  project     = "worklark-218609"
  zone        = "us-central1-a"
}

# Node pool configuration
resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_pool" {
  name       = "worklark-node-pool"
  cluster    = "${google_container_cluster.primary.name}"
  node_count = 3

  node_config {
    machine_type = "f1-micro"
    disk_size_gb = 10         # Set the initial disk size
    preemptible  = true
  }

  management {
    auto_repair  = true
    auto_upgrade = true
  }
}

# configuration
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name               = "worklark-cluster"
  logging_service    = "none"
  monitoring_service = "none"

  addons_config {
    kubernetes_dashboard {
      disabled = false # Configure the Kubernetes dashboard
    }

    http_load_balancing {
      disabled = false # Configure the Kubernetes dashboard
    }
  }

  remove_default_node_pool = "true"

  node_pool {
    name = "default-pool"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "default" {
  name        = "http-https"
  network     = "${google_container_cluster.primary.network}"
  description = "Enable HTTP and HTTPS access"

  direction = "INGRESS"

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80", "443"]
  }
}
```